# What is a model in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm using a class based views and
I have problem with understanding models in Django.

For example: 
**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .models import Author


class AuthorListView(ListView):
    model = Author
```

What is a "model"?

**models.py:**

```
class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{first_name} {last_name}".format(first_name=self.first_name, last_name=self.last_name)
```

Somebody can give me a full explanation od "model" at views.py? 
I don't want to use "items" which I don't understand.

Comment: A 'model' is the core concept of an MVC framework, of which Django is one (although in Django it's MTV). You should read the documentation linked by Chris Brown and perhaps some really basic intro to MVC and object oriented programming like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller.

Comment: If you are asking this question, it would be worth using function based views until you understand it. Class based views have a lot of implicit behavior and you really need to understand concepts like these to use them properly. Function based views involve doing things more manually, but in your case I think it would help you understand what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A model is the definition of an object. These objects are usually saved to your database. When you run migrations, Django uses this definition to create the schema for the new table. Thus, after migrating, you will have first_name and last_name columns in your table (along with many that Django adds by default). Read this: [Django Model Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/)